# Quickfix with makeprg running in a different directory

Tags: quickfix, makeprg, path

How can I start a build with my `makeprg` running in a different directory than the working directory of vim and still catch errors in quickfix so that I can jump between them?

The problem is that quickfix doesn't know how to find the error locations as reported by the `makeprg` due to the different paths. (The particular build system I have in mind is CMake and Ninja.)

I know that there is a path variable in Vim that to which I can add the other path. The last time I tried that it seemed less than convenient but maybe there's a good autocommand trick to fix that.

Currently I set my `makeprg` to a shell script that pipes build errors through a `sed` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make and Ninja offer a `-C` flag. From Ninja:

```
-C DIR   change to DIR before doing anything else
```

If I run Ninja in a shell with the `-C` flag pointing somewhere that isn't the working directory, then the reported paths are the same as if I had `cd`'d over to the build directory. Nonetheless, Vim knows to become more intelligent when you use this flag in your `makeprg` and quickfix can then figure out where it should jump to. In the quickfix window, the reported paths are changed to be relative to Vim's working directory.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if your ninja output directory is '$SRC/out'

```
:set makeprg=ninja\ -C\ $SRC/out
```

Note: the space should escape by backslash

Comment: Welcome to our site! It is always useful to link to the relevant help topic: [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27) :)