# Quickfix stack doesn't work when using make -j

Tags: quickfix, makeprg, errorformat

As mentioned in [other questions](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2332/6627), using `make -C buildpath` as `makeprg` in Vim and the appropriate [errorformat](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27errorformat%27) triggers the nice handling of the [quickfix directory stack](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix-directory-stack).

That is, the quickfix uses the "Enter/Leave directory" printed by `make` to append the right path to the detected files, so you can jump to them from the quickfix.

But it seems that it only works if `make` is used as single thread, i.e. `-j1`. 
When using `-jN` with N > 1 then the directory stack seems to be messed in my experience, and the quickfix doesn't get the right paths.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! While providing the links is helpful, it is even better to also include the necessary content so that your question is self-contained even if the links die. Please [edit] your question to that end. As far as your issue goes, fundamentally the output from parallel builds is mixed up--it's non-deterministic, even. I'm not sure of any good way to recover the correct ordering short of logging prefixes on all commands with the target they're attached too or some-such (and I'm not even sure how I would do that)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! I've updated a bit the question to make it more self-contained.
And thanks to the answer from Matt I've been able to fix it using the `-O` option on `make` that keeps the terminal output of make on sync even if it uses multiple threads internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Vim, as it's your make utility who sets output order.

For GNU make [read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html).

Comment: Thanks @Matt, the ‘--output-sync’ (‘-O’) option of make did the trick.